# Sqoop - can I bulk import multiple mysql tables to one HBase/Hive table

Tags: sqoop

If I have multiple similar tables, e.g:

table A: `"users"`, columns: `user_name, user_id, user_address, etc etc`

table B: `"customers"` columns: `customer_name, customer_id, customer_address, etc etc`

table C: `"employee"` columns: `employee_name, employee_id, employe_address, etc etc`

Is it possible that using Sqoop to import the three tables into one HBase or Hive table? So After the import, I have one HBase table contains all the records in table A, B, C ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's definitely possible if the tables are somehow related. A free-form query can be used in Sqoop to do exactly that. In this case, the free-form query would be a join. For example, when importing into Hive:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql:///mydb --username hue --password hue --query "SELECT * FROM users JOIN customers ON users.id=customers.user_id JOIN employee ON users.id = employee.user_id WHERE \$CONDITIONS" --split-by oozie_job.id --target-dir "/tmp/hue" --hive-import --hive-table hive-table
```

Similarly, for Hbase:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql:///mydb --username hue --password hue --query "SELECT * FROM users JOIN customers ON users.id=customers.user_id JOIN employee ON users.id = employee.user_id WHERE \$CONDITIONS" --split-by oozie_job.id --hbase-table hue --column-family c1
```

The key ingredient in all of this is the SQL statement being provided:

```
SELECT * FROM users JOIN customers ON users.id=customers.user_id JOIN employee ON users.id = employee.user_id WHERE \$CONDITIONS
```

For more information on free-form queries, check out http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.4/SqoopUserGuide.html#_free_form_query_imports.